# Second order differential confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am slight confused on this problem and just wonder if anyone could. I have an idea, but would just like to get it confirmed and if my understanding is correct.

Q) Find a satisfying the following $y''+yy'=0$ for $y(0)=5$ & $y'(0)=0$

My working so far:

(1)$y'=p$ (2)$y''=\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}*\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}*P$

subbing (1)&(2) into my differential equation I get the following:

$\frac{dp}{dy}(p)+yp=0$ $\rightarrow$ $\frac{dp}{dy}+y=0$

$dp=-ydy$ $\rightarrow$ $\int dp=-\int y dy$

$p=\frac{-y^2}{2}+c$ $\rightarrow$ $p+\frac{y^2}{2}=c$ (3)

subbing (1) into (3) I get:

$y'+\frac{y^2}{2}=c$ (4)

So now if I rearrange do use separation of variables I get the intergral of the form:

$\int dx= \int \frac{2}{2c-y^2}$

Now this is the part I would like to know. Can I let $2c=a^2$? My reason for this is as it an constant it could be anything.

Comment: So try with two cases. Mainly $C$ depends on domain of function in solution!

Comment: You forgot you were given $y(0)=5$ and $y'(0)=0$. Plug that into your equation (4), and you'll see your $c$ is $25/2$.

Comment: Thank you guys as well for the response it has cleared some very much needed info for me. Once again much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** Case $C>0$ then with substitution $2C=a^2$ and general solution is $x+D=\dfrac{1}{a}\ln\dfrac{a+y}{a-y}$.

**(2)** Case $C<0$ then with substitution $2C=-b^2$ and general solution is $x+D=\dfrac{-2}{b}\arctan\dfrac{y}{b}$.

These solutions are the same. In fact
$$\arctan z=\dfrac{1}{2i}\log\dfrac{1+iz}{1-iz}$$
for main branch of logarithm. So if you let $C>0$ or $C<0$ no fault really occurs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, it much appreciated.